# How can I update all except the max value in a group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the table below:

```
+----+----------+-----+-------
| ID | animal| pets | age  
+----+----------+-----+------
|  1 | pig   | y    | 19
|  2 | pig   | y    | 21
|  3 | horse | y    | 23
|  4 | dog   | y    | 45
|  5 | dog   | y    | 56
|  6 | cat   | n    | 34
|  7 | cat   | y    | 56
```

I need help building a query that sets Pets to 'n' for the rows of that kind of animal that have an age thats less than the maximum value of age for that animal that is set to 'y'. So there could only be one row for each animal set to 'y' and it must be that with the max age so the resulting table should look like this:

```
+----+----------+-----+-------
| ID | animal| pets | age  
+----+----------+-----+------
|  1 | pig   | n    | 19
|  2 | pig   | y    | 21
|  3 | horse | y    | 23
|  4 | dog   | n    | 45
|  5 | dog   | y    | 56
|  6 | cat   | n    | 34
|  7 | cat   | y    | 56
```

Comment: what happens for "equal max" conditions e.g. 2 dogs of age 56?

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you provided the actual table name

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS:** you can use `subquery` but in case of same ages it will not be updated:

```
UPDATE temp SET pets = 'n'
WHERE age in ( SELECT t.age
FROM temp t
INNER JOIN (SELECT animal, MAX(age) age 
            FROM temp GROUP BY animal) t1 ON t1.animal = t.animal AND t1.age <> t.age)
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/91ea9/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Pets
    (ID int, ANIMAL varchar2(5), PETS varchar2(1), AGE int)
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO Pets (ID, ANIMAL, PETS, AGE)
         VALUES (1, 'pig', 'y', 19)
    INTO Pets (ID, ANIMAL, PETS, AGE)
         VALUES (2, 'pig', 'y', 21)
    INTO Pets (ID, ANIMAL, PETS, AGE)
         VALUES (3, 'horse', 'y', 23)
    INTO Pets (ID, ANIMAL, PETS, AGE)
         VALUES (4, 'dog', 'y', 45)
    INTO Pets (ID, ANIMAL, PETS, AGE)
         VALUES (5, 'dog', 'y', 56)
    INTO Pets (ID, ANIMAL, PETS, AGE)
         VALUES (6, 'cat', 'n', 34)
    INTO Pets (ID, ANIMAL, PETS, AGE)
         VALUES (7, 'cat', 'y', 56)
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
update pets
set pets = case when age = (select max(age) from pets p where pets.animal = p.animal)
                then 'Y' 
                else 'N' 
           end
;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/91ea9/1/0)**:

```
select
*
from pets

| ID | ANIMAL | PETS | AGE |
|----|--------|------|-----|
|  1 |    pig |    N |  19 |
|  2 |    pig |    Y |  21 |
|  3 |  horse |    Y |  23 |
|  4 |    dog |    N |  45 |
|  5 |    dog |    Y |  56 |
|  6 |    cat |    N |  34 |
|  7 |    cat |    Y |  56 |
```

I'm not sure why you need this as an update. A view would be far simpler, e.g.

```
select ID, ANIMAL, AGE
      , case when AGE = max(AGE) over(partition by animal) then 'Y' else 'N' end pets_2
from pets
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code,

```
 update your_table_name a 
 inner join your_table_name b on a.animal = b.animal
 set a.pet='n' 
 where a.age < (select max(b.age));
```